# python function returning unnecessary tuple values

Tags: python, function, numpy, csv, tuples

i'm trying to write a python function that reads a csv file and converts it's into a numpy array. I have to then calculate it's mean and median. This is the question:

[image]

And this is the code that i've written

```
def calc_stats(csvF):
  data = np.loadtxt(csvF, delimiter=',')
  meanF = sum(data)/len(data)
  
  data.sort()
  if len(data)%2 == 0:
    m1 = data[len(data)//2]
    m2 = data[len(data)//2 - 1]
    medianF = (m1+m2)/2
  else:
    medianF = data[len(data)//2]
  
  returnVal = (meanF, medianF)
  
  return returnVal
```

You can see in the question the output we're expecting but the output i'm getting is this:

```
array([  9.65666667,  15.89      ,  13.43666667,   5.4       ]), array([  1.27,   3.99,  11.73,  19.66]))
```

I don't understand why i'm getting these extra values. I can't seem to figure out what i'm doing wrong. Kindly help.

Comment: `data` as loaded is a 2d numpy array, shape (3,4).  `len` and `sum` are Python functions that operate on the first dimension.  If you want the sum of all values use `np.sum` and `np.size`.  Or as suggested in the answer, flatten the array to 1d with `data=data.ravel()`.  In `numpy` you need to keep track of array shapes, using `print(...shape`) when there's any confusion.

Comment: @hpaulj oh okay!! thank you so much. This clears things up a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these values are the mean and median of each column you do not sum all of data
you have to reshape (flatten the array to be a list) your data

```
data = np.loadtxt(csvF, delimiter=',')
data = data.reshape(-1)
meanF = sum(data) / len(data)
```

Comment: How do i fix this? I need to sum all the values